Validate digital signature using TCPDF PHP
I created a signed PDF file by using TCPDF.
I used this function: setSignature()
Howerver I can not find any function to validate this signed PDF file.
Following example 52 of TCPDF documment, they guildle me to use Acrobat Reader but I want to do it by myself (without using another app).
Can you show me the way to validate this signed PDF file signed by function setSignature()?

Validating the signature is the job of the PDF reader. Why do you want to do it yourself?

I have a project to write a module app about digital signature. I just completed a half that I can sign into PDF file. Now I need to validate this signed PDF file (by myself because this is my module app).

There is a JS solution here.

Do you think that I sign PDF file by TCPDF and verify by another lib? I don't know how it work.

TCPDF can't check a signature, if that's your question.

I want to keep PDF format after signed. I tried OpenSSL then format convert to .txt. How about verify-pdf you recommend to me?

I have never used the verify-pdf library, I just did a Google search to find it.
